# feed command output into for /f

Tags: batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

Is it possible to pipe the command output to the following batch file as its input?

I'd like to feed output from commands such as `dir c:\temp |find "05" |find "new"` to the following batch file. Because my command have many variations and I don't want to edit the batch file every time I need it, thus, I'm looking for a way to feed the command output directly to the batch file, instead of having the batch file generate its input using `dir /b`. Basically, what I'd like to achieve is to find from a list of files (generated using the dir command) the file whose name contains the highest number (achieved using the batch file.) Example:

```
today123.txt
today456.txt
tomorrow123.txt
tomorrow456.txt
```

With the dir command, I can filter off today or tomorrow, leaving only two files. Then, feed these two files to the batch file and have it select the one which has 456 in the file name. Of course, this is a simplified example. I may have more files and more groups than those in the example.

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b ^|sort /r ^|findstr /r [0-9]') do (
  set "filename=%%a"
  goto done
)
:done
echo the highest found is %filename%
exit /b 0
```

Comment: so you want to run it as `dir c:\temp | find "05" | find "new"` and pipe the output as input to the batch file?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't know much about batch files. The batch file finds the file whose name has the highest number. What I want is using the dir command to generate a list of files and have the batch file find out which file has the highest number.

Comment: @Gerhard the dir command may vary. It could be 06, 10, 12, 03, etc. and it may not be new but old, or something else.

Comment: You can use more to take output piped to a batch file and process it in a batch file in some circumstances.  I'm just fining what you want to acomplish a little confusing.  You could also make a batch file that does all the DIR etc and uses arguments you supply yo change what its searching on each time

Comment: please clarify: the highest number of all files / highest number of one group (starting with the same text)  / highest number of each group? (btw: `batch` is a really terrible choice for this)

Comment: btw: it would help tremendously when the file with the highest number would also be the most recently created. Can we assume this is the case?

Comment: @Stephan not the highest number of all files but the highest number of the filtered files. Using the example in my post, if I do a dir and find "today", files whose name doesn't contain today will be filtered off. I need the file name in the remaining files whose name has the highest number, today456.txt in my extremely simple case. Not sure if it would be the most recently created in its own group.

Comment: @ben are you suggesting replace "dir /b" in the batch file with "dir /s /b |find %%1 |find %%2"? Good thought. Let me try that and see what happens.

Comment: @joehua, it may help if you were to provide a genuine problem with and actual set of files and real search strings. Currently there is a list of four files, none of which contain either `05` or `new`, despite the fact you've provided those in your example command, _(which does not output content of that type and format either)_. Please edit your question, provide a directory of files, a defined problem, the code you would use in that scenario, and what issue is exhibited, when using your code for that specific problem. We need to be able to replicate your issue and environment to assist you.

Comment: This is probably the easiest, simplest solution. I replaced the `'dir /b ^|sort /r ^|findstr /r [0-9]'` with `'dir %1 /b ^|find "%2" ^|find "%3" ^|sort /r ^|findstr /r [0-9]'` and it does what I wanted.

Comment: @Gerhard I haven't had time to try them yet. I'll test them tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a number of ways. This is one of them:

```
@echo off & set filename=
if "%~5" == "" set "myfind=dir /b ^| find "%~2" ^| find "%~3" ^| find "%~4" ^|sort /r ^|findstr /r [0-9]"
if "%~4" == "" set "myfind=dir /b ^| find "%~2" ^| find "%~3" ^|sort /r ^|findstr /r [0-9]"
if "%~3" == "" set "myfind=dir /b ^| find "%~2" ^|sort /r ^|findstr /r [0-9]"
if "%~2" == "" set "myfind=dir /b ^|sort /r ^|findstr /r [0-9]"

pushd "%~1"
for /f %%a in ('%myfind%') do (
  set "filename=%%a"
  goto done
)
:done
popd
if not defined filename echo Not match found & exit /b 1
echo the highest found is %filename%
exit /b 0
```

Typically you would run it as:

```
batch-file-name.cmd "C:\path\to\search" "search1" "search2" "search3"
```

for instance, using your example:

```
batch-file-name.cmd "c:\temp" "05" "new"
```

or even extend the search:

```
batch-file-name.cmd "c:\temp" "05" "new" ".txt"
```

How it works:
We set the search string each time in the case an additional `find` command is required. for now we have up to three finds and one path, but it can be extended to more. You have to set them in descending order though.
I also added an additional statement `if not defined filename` to ensure you are alerted if a find is not matched.

Answer (score 0):

The following gets the highest of a given group:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "search=today"
set "max=0"
for %%a in (%search%*.txt) do (
  set "name=%%~na"
  set "number=!name:%search%=!"
  if !number! gtr !max! set /a max=number
)
echo max number for %search% is %max%
set "highest=%search%%max%.txt"
echo %highest%
```

Attention, there is no errorchecking at all, so it depends on the correct format of the file names. (errorchecking can be added when needed)

To get the search string as a parameter, simply replace `set "search=today"` with `set "search=%~1"`

Comment: Thanks for spending time working on my problem. The answer is beyond my limited knowledge on shell command. I don't know how to modify it to suit my need. How do I add a search directory and a second search term?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you look for A) a group (input1)  and B) for the highest number in that group (determined by my code). Where does a second input fit in?